# How to replace parentheses with symbol of other font so that they are expandable?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, brackets, delimiters

I use Bitstream Charter for my document, but I'm not satisfied with the appearance of round parentheses. I'd like to replace them with the parentheses from Palatino, both in text and math mode. In math mode I managed to change the symbol font to CM with the instructions from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font.) and [here](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf), but now the parentheses do not automatically scale with `\left(` and `\right)`. A manual adjustment with `\big`, `\Big`, etc also does not work. The parentheses always stay the normal (text) size as shown below.

The example code

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{alt}{\hyphenchar\font=-1}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{alt}{m}{n}{
  <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * alt
  <10.95> alt10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> alt12
  }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{alt}{U}{alt}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{alt}{`(}{alt}{`(}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{alt}{`)}{alt}{`)}

\begin{document}
Inserting eq.~(2b) into eq.~(1) yields
\begin{equation}
A = B \left( \frac{A-\phi}{c \left(1+E^{1/m} \right)} + \frac{1}{2} \right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: an example output formula]

My principal question is how to make the parentheses expandable. Less importantly, I'd also like to know how to change them to a font other than CM (since the CM symbols are a bit too light in comparison to Charter) and how to substitute them also in text mode (in the above example you can see that they are still in Charter).

Comment: You have to add `NEXTCHAR` features in the tfm file and also `TOP`, `REP`, `MIDDLE` and `BOTTOM` for the larger composite versions.

Comment: For text, the best solution I'm aware of would involve creating a virtual font using characters from the two source fonts. However, this will not look good as you will either lose kerning information altogether or you'll have kerns which fail to match one or other of your character sets. So the spacing will be wrong.