# Adjust / and \backslash symbols in Fourier

Tags: fonts, delimiters, math-fonts, fourier

In [Fourier](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fourier), the non-sized slashes `/` and `\backslash` are, in my opinion, too small and does not tilt enough compared to their sized version. For example, writing `a / b` and `a \big/ b`, we obtain something like below:

[image: a / b]

Perhaps it is not very easy to see just like this, but the first slash does not tilt as much as the second one.

I know that in `fourier.sty`, we have

```latex
\DeclareMathDelimiter{/}{\mathord}{operators}{047}{largesymbols}{177}
```

which explains why `/` behaves different compared to `\big/`, as they point to different symbols (similar for `\backslash`). Perhaps one could change this to

```latex
\DeclareMathDelimiter{/}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{177}{largesymbols}{177}
```

such that they point to the same symbol, and then in some way rescale and reposition it. Changing only this line, however, we get

[image: a / b but worse]

where first and foremost the slash is at a very bad position, and secondly has the same size as `\big/`.

How can I make the non-sized slashes tilt as much as their sized versions, and make them slightly bigger than what they currently are? I still want to be able to simply write `a / b`, but where the slashes are coherent to their sized versions.

Update: [`mathdesign`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathdesign)'s slashes looks good. However, I don't know how to substitute Fourier's with these. Perhaps [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font.) can be of help.

Note: This seems to be very much related to [this closed post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147254/how-to-replace-parentheses-with-symbol-of-other-font-so-that-they-are-expandable). Hopefully this can be remained open, as I'm trying to work on a solution.

Answer (score 2):

As `mathdesign`'s slashes are very similar, it was somewhat easy to replace these two slashes with their counterpart in the Utopia part of `mathdesign`.

What I obtained was

[image: result]

Here is the corresponding code on how to generate this:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[draft=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fourier}

\makeatletter
% slash
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{mdput}{\hyphenchar \font =45}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{mdput}{m}{n}{
   <->s * [0.94]  mdputr7t
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{mdput}{b}{n}{
   <->s * [0.94]  mdputb7t
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{newoperators}{OT1}{mdput}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{newoperators}{bold}{OT1}{mdput}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{/}{\mathord}{newoperators}{047}{largesymbols}{177}

% backslash
\DeclareFontFamily{OMS}{mdput}{\skewchar \font =48}
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{mdput}{m}{n}{
   <->s * [0.94]  mdputr7y
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{mdput}{b}{n}{
   <->s * [0.94]  mdputb7y
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{newsymbols}{OMS}{mdput}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{newsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{mdput}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\backslash}{\mathord}{newsymbols}{110}{largesymbols}{178}

% just to patch sized delimiters in the Fourier font
\def\resetMathstrut@{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{%
    \mathchardef\@tempa\mathcode`\(\relax
    \def\@tempb##1"##2##3{\the\textfont"##3\char"}%
    \expandafter\@tempb\meaning\@tempa \relax
  }%
  \ht\Mathstrutbox@1.2\ht\z@ \dp\Mathstrutbox@1.2\dp\z@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a demonstration of slash:~$a / b = (a / b)$.

This is a demonstration of backslash:~$a \backslash b = (a \backslash b)$.
\begin{gather*}
  a / b
\;=\;
  a \big/ b
\\
  a \backslash b
\;=\;
  a \big\backslash b
\\
  / \mspace{-6mu} \big/
\\
  \backslash \mspace{-6mu} \big\backslash
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

This was achieved by looking at how `mathdesign`'s Utopia loads the symbol fonts `operator` and `symbol` and port it here.